# Could not load file or assembly 'WpfPDFViewer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

i import WpfPDFViewer a whole project into our big project and set this project to x86
and our project using Any CPU

i do it in this way, success in this small project, got error in big project

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxs_ao6uuBDUTnpWUkJUR0FSVEk/edit?usp=sharing

however, it got error Could not load file or assembly 'WpfPDFViewer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all dependencies for WpfPDFViewer?

You may need this DLLs:

> AxInterop.AcrorPDFLib.dll
>
> Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll

And be sure, that both dlls are in the same folder as your .exe is.

Comment: No need any more, because i import a whole project into it and already test success in a small WPF project, just meet difficulty when integrated with a big project

Comment: yes same setting, x86 for WpfPDFViewer, i updated a success one, https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxs_ao6uuBDUTnpWUkJUR0FSVEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And if you change your big-project to x86 for testing?

Comment: extremely thanks, this is it, after set another project in whole solution to x86, it success